# Mock Class Constructor being extended in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am receiving `An argument for 'options' was not provided.` when I try to mock a class with a constructor.

Color.test.ts

```js
...
describe('TEST getColorById', () => {
    describe('GIVEN color id', () => {
        // mockColor will return orange as color
        const mockRoot = mockColor({
            id: 1,
        });

        const mockReturn = { id: 1, color: 'orange' };

        class MockColor extends Color {
            // overrides the response of post for await colorClass.getColorById with the expected mockReturn
            public async post(): Promise<any> {
                return { response: [mockReturn] };
            }
        }

        // ? how can I simulate instantiating class with constructor
        const colorClass = new MockColor();

        describe('WHEN calling getColorById', () => {
            test('THEN it loads color info', async () => {
                const received = await colorClass.getColorById({ id: 1 });
                expect(received).toEqual([mockRoot]);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Color.ts

```js
...
 
export class Color {
    private token: string;
    private baseUrl: string;

    constructor(options: { token; baseUrl? }) {
        super(options);
        this.token = options.token;
        this.baseUrl = options.baseUrl;
    }

    async getColorById(object: { id: number }): Promise<ColorRoot> {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to mock data returned from an endpoint, without having to mock internal calls like this, try using the Mock Service Workers package https://www.npmjs.com/package/msw.

Comment: For this question: you want to turn `new MockColor();` into `new MockColor({});`

Comment: @Derek Thank you for sharing the msw package however I'm inheriting this project and I can't rewrite all the mocks with this huge codebase. The second suggestion works. Thanks a lot.